# how to open a website from asp.net window from using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

How do you present a hyperlink to some specific URL like https://stackoverflow.com/ in a desktop application written with windows forms?

kindly suggest the best way to do this, the application is written in c#.

Comment: `asp.net window application using c#`?

Comment: First web search hit for "winforms hyperlink": [Build Hyperlinks into Your Client App with the Windows Forms LinkLabel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188769.aspx). Please show research.

Answer (score 2):

I hope my understanding is correct but if you want to open a link try using this.

```
Process.Start("link here");
```

Comment: your answers work here

Comment: @AvinashJha So my understanding was correct? is it what you wanted to do?

Comment: yes its workable for me

Comment: Ok, but using Process.Start will always open on your default browser. You can resolve your problem if its already ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new control and inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Label`. It's pretty simple and described [here](http://mattberther.com/2005/07/10/a-winforms-hyperlink-control).

Comment: it's better if he uses a linklabel

Answer (score 0):

If its a static link, why not just use regular html?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" >link</a>
```

Or replace the actual link with some property from your codebehind

Comment: looking for window form not for web application.

Comment: I see, i'll edit your question if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

If u want to open a website inside your application you should use `WebBrowser` control. Add it to you winform and in your code provide the link to open the corresponding webpage. Your own customised browser.